# combine two id into a new table?

Tags: python, mysql, database, text-processing, information-retrieval

i had a task about text processing and i don't know how to combine some columns from separate tables into one table

so here is the case:
i have a table named `list` with `id_doc`, and `title` columns
then i create a new table named `term_list` which contains a list of result terms when i do some text processing to titles from `list`.

the `term_list` table have `id_term`, `term`, `df`, and `idf` column. Lastly, i want to have a table named `term_freq` which has columns `id`, `id_term`, `id_doc`, `tf`, and `normalized_tf`

example :
table `list` is like this:

```
id_doc             titles
  11      information retrieval system
  12          operating system
  13         business information
```

table `term_list` is below this:

```
id_term     term         df    idf
   21     information     2     --
   22      retrieval      1     --
   23       system        2     --
   24      operating      1     --
   25       business      1     --
```

I want to ask how to create a table `term_freq` so that the table becomes like this?

```
id    id_term     id_doc    tf      normalized_tf
31      21          11       1           -- 
32      22          11       1           --
33      23          11       1           --
34      24          12       1           --
35      23          12       1           --
36      25          13       1           --
37      21          13       1           --
```

the main problem is i have to join `id_term` and `id_doc` into one table that one `id_doc` has relation to several `id_term` but i don't know how to correlate because `list` and `term_list`doesn't have any similar column.

Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over rows in `term_list`:

```
SELECT id_term, term FROM term_list
```

for each `term` make:

```
SELECT id_doc FROM list WHERE titles LIKE "term"
```

and saves pairs `id_term` and `id_doc` in the table `term_freq`.